# What is the technical definition of a react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a beginner in react and of all the information i have gathered so far is that you can create a custom hook in react. **But what qualifies as a hook?** If I create a normal Javascript function and begin its name with **`use`** Is that now a hook?

**Example**

```
  const useMultiple = (number, multipliedBy) => {
    return [number, number * multipliedBy];
  };

  const [number, multipliedBy] = useMultiple(2, 3);
```

Can i call **useMultiple** my custom hook? Are there any **rules or requirements** for something to be a hook?

Comment: No, it's a ordinary function.

Comment: In a nutshell, I would describe a hook as a way of _hooking into_ the component's lifecycle. So, if there are some repetitive parts of logic executed upon component mount/update/dismantle, you may extract those into hooks. So, I would say, your example function _can_ be considered a hook (if you wouldn't want to use it outside of components as a regular helper method later, in which case `use*` naming convention would look rather confusing). However corresponding official docs section may describe that way better than I do.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html